# Is there an annotation or trick to ensure that Entities always clear after save/update?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Am having this problem where a config value is being updated by several sources in the actual database, but gets out of date in the front-end because Doctrine is returning the object's last save state.

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: What do you actually do? A question like that is like "I have a needle and sometimes when i jump into the haystack, it hurts, how can i jump so it stops hurting"

Comment: The question I'd be asking is why are there several sources updating the same value with seemingly no constraints on data integrity.

Comment: That's definitely a new reference Sam!  The ER is being used by an in-house front-end to view data that is being managed by a up-and-down cluster of machines on AWS.  I could craft an easy example that is, within the ZF2 app that uses the ER: a listing of all hours of the day, and the magic number for each hour.  The secondary processes that run disparately, modify the magic numbers.  The modifications are not reflected in the list.  It's not a question of data integrity, the systems are doing their job, the list is out of sync.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same EntityManager instance for fetching those items? The items that are in memory should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You could register an event listener on update/save events (see \Doctrine\ORM\Events) and when the event fires up run the clear ($entityName) method of the EntityManager.